# Superscript in C++ console output

Tags: c++, superscript

I'd like to have my program output "cm<sup>2</sup>" (cm squared).

How do make a superscript 2?

Comment: Can you output HTML and display that in a window, updating with AJAX?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Zan said, it depends what character encoding your standard output supports.  If it supports Unicode , you can use the encoding for ²([U+00B2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b2/index.htm)).  If it supports the same Unicode encoding for source files and standard output, you can just embed it in the file.  For example, my GNU/Linux system uses UTF-8 for both, so this works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "cm²" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for just Unicode. On ISO-8859-1, ² is `char(0xB2)`. Since my Windows system uses that for source files and console output, I too can embed it directly in my source files.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something C++ can do on its own.

You would need to use a specific feature of your console system.

I am not aware of any consoles or terminals that implement super-script. I might be wrong though.

Comment: It depends on the available characters and the encoding used. With [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to accomplish this task for the purpose of making a quadratic equation solver. Writing `ax²` inside a `cout <<` by holding ALT while typing 253 displayed properly in the source code only, BUT NOT in the console. When running the program, it appeared as a light colored rectangle instead of a superscript 2.

A simple solution to this seems to be casting the integer 253 as a char, like this... `(char)253`.

Because our professor discourages us from using 'magic numbers', I declared it as a constant variable... `const int superScriptTwo = 253; //ascii value of super script two`.

Then, where I wanted the superscript 2 to appear in the console, I cast my variable as a `char` like this...
`cout << "f(x) = ax" << (char)superScriptTwo << " + bx + c";` and it displayed perfectly.

Perhaps it's even easier just to create it as a `char` to begin with, and not worry about casting it. This code will also print a super script 2 to the console when compiled and run in VS2013 on my Lenovo running Windows 7...

```
char ssTwo = 253;
cout << ssTwo << endl;
```

I hope someone will find this useful. This is my first post, ever, so I do apologize in advance if I accidentally violated any Stack Overflow protocols for answering a question posted 5+ years ago. Any such occurrence was not intentional.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with Zan.

Basic C++ does not have any inbuilt functionality to print superscripts or subscripts. You need to use any additional UI library.

Comment: Technically speaking, C++ doesn't have functionality for outputting ANY specific character.  Even for basic alphanumeric characters like 'a' or '2' C++ has no functionality to actually output them.  All it is capable of doing is converting those literals into character codes that are then interpreted by the output stream they are sent to.  Generally this results in seeing an 'a' or a '2' on the screen but given some weird console and/or font system you could get anything.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout << cm\x00B2;`
writes cm^2.

Answer (score -1):

For super scripting or sub scripting you need to use ascii value of the letter or number.

Eg: Super scripting 2 for x² we  need to get the `ascii value of super script of 2` (search in google for that) ie - `253`. For typing ascii character you have to do `alt + 253` here, you can write a any number, but its 253 in this case.

Eg:-`cout<<"x²";`

So, now it should display `x²` on the black screen.

Comment: Superscript characters don't have ASCII codes.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try ASCII?
Declare a character and give it an ASCII value of `253` and then print the character.
So your code should go like this;

```
char ch = 253;
cout<<"cm"<<ch;
```

This will definitely print cm<sup>2</sup>.

Comment: No, it actually prints the ² with the ch value passed in.